# Create a Map with "Struct" in NSDictionary in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I want to Create a NSMutableDictionary with an Integer Mapping to an strucuter(struct).
Example:

```
int nVar = 1;
typedef struct 
{
  NSString *pstrName;
}sSampleStruct;
sSampleStruct *sObject = {@"test"};
NSMutableDictioary *pSampleMap = [[NSMutableDictioary allo] init];
[pSampleMap setObject:sObject forKey:[[nsnumber alloc] initwithint:nVar];
```

This is what i want to do? But as struct is not an object its throwing a warning?
Is thr any way i can create a dictionary with strutures.
Or is thr any other way to create a map with structure?

Kindly reply soon.....

Thank you
Pradeep.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at [NSValue](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000177-value_withObjCType_):

```
[pSampleMap setObject:[NSValue value:&sObject withObjCType:@encode(sSampleStruct)] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nInt]];
```

Also, you're having a memory leak in `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:nVar]` and your code will not even complile since Objective-C is case-sensitive.

Comment: Hey thanks.....tat was really a quick reply...It works.
The sample i wrote was just to make my requirement clear.
Thanks for pointing to the memory leak.

Comment: @Joost how to get back the struct?

Answer (score 8):

You are right in that both the key and value in a NSDictionary must be objects. What you're looking for is `NSValue`.

From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> An NSValue object is a simple container for a single C or Objective-C data item. It can hold any of the scalar types such as int, float, and char, as well as pointers, structures, and object ids. The purpose of this class is to allow items of such data types to be added to collections such as instances of NSArray and NSSet, which require their elements to be objects. NSValue objects are always immutable.

Something like (with a slight cleanup of the code):

```
typedef struct 
{
    NSString *pstrName;
} sSampleStruct;

// Changed sObject to non-pointer so it can be initialized with a literal
sSampleStruct sObject = {@"test"};

// Corrected spelling of NSMutableDictionary
NSMutableDictionary *pSampleMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Changed to [NSNumber numberWithInt:] to avoid leaking memory
// Corrected spelling and capitalization of NSNumber
[pSampleMap setObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:&sObject] 
               forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nVar]];
```

Comment: Hey im pretty impressed with the way you answered it...
Thanks a lot....
I would be needing a lot of help...as i need to finish of a tool.by end of this week..hope this forum helps me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSData for wrap your structure.
Below is my solution, its work for me:

```
// this is complex structure SIO2Object. Use you custom initialization instead of this 
SIO2object *el = ( SIO2object * )sio2ResourceGetObject(sio2->_SIO2resource, @"User/11/..." );

NSMutableDictionary *elements = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSData *elData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&el length:sizeof(el)];
[elements setObject:elData forKey:@"first"];

SIO2object *newEl = nil;
NSData *newData = [elements objectForKey:@"first"];
[newData getBytes:&newEl];
//there newEl is equal to el
```

Answer (score 2):

or if you're familiar with c++:

`std::map<sSampleStruct,int> myDictionary;`

Answer (score 1):

you can use NSDictionary, but the features are only available from the CF-interface:

```
/* define our custom key callbacks */
CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks keyCallbacks;

keyCallbacks.version = 0; /* default */
keyCallbacks.retain = 0; /* no retain performed */
keyCallbacks.release = 0; /* no release performed */
keyCallbacks.copyDescription = 0; /* potentially applicable */
keyCallbacks.equal = 0; /* potentially applicable */
keyCallbacks.hash = 0; /* potentially applicable */

/* note: if you prefer to use NSNumber for keys,
    then you should use the default key callbacks.
    this illustrates what you could do if you wanted to use int keys.
*/

/* define our custom value callbacks */
CFDictionaryValueCallBacks valueCallbacks;
/* see per-field comments at keyCallbacks */
valueCallbacks.version = 0;
valueCallbacks.retain = 0;
valueCallbacks.release = 0;
valueCallbacks.copyDescription = 0;
valueCallbacks.equal = 0;

CFAllocatorRef allocator = kCFAllocatorDefault;
CFIndex capacity = 0; /* no hint in this example - resizes as needed */

NSMutableDictionary * myNewDictionary = (NSMutableDictionary*)
   CFDictionaryCreateMutable(allocator, capacity, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks);

/*
for insertions/values/keys:
  - use a pointer to the key/value if the value is larger than a pointer.
    this may require dynamic memory allocation and use of reference counting
    since the keys/values must live in memory as long as the dictionary exists
*/
```